# function wont accept iterator to auto_ptr

Tags: c++, standard-library, auto-ptr, huffman-code

I wrote some flawed Huff compression code that I was trying to fix. The first thing I did was to switch the pointers to `auto_ptr` (There are reasons I didn't use another smart pointer). I create a vector of `auto_ptr` but when I try to pass an auto_ptr to a function by `*(vector.begin())` it doesn't work.

My function code I'm trying to pass ownership to (it's a member function as set_node):

```
struct Node {
    int weight;
    char litteral;
    auto_ptr<Node> childL;
    auto_ptr<Node> childR;
    void set_node(int w, char l, auto_ptr<Node>& L(), auto_ptr<Node>& R()){
        weight = w;
        litteral = l;
        childL = L;
        childR = R;
    }
};
```

and this is how I try to call it (p is a node):

```
p.set_node(w, '*', *nodes->begin(), *(nodes->begin()+1));
```

This is how the vector is declared:

```
vector<auto_ptr<Node> >* nodes = new vector<auto_ptr<Node> >;
```

Comment: Why `L()` and `R()` and not just `L` and `R`?

Comment: You want `std::unique_ptr<>` instead.

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov - Only if tr1/C++11 is available.

Comment: The standard forbids the use of `vector<auto_ptr<T> >`. You cannot expect it to work correctly.

Comment: The copy constructor of auto_ptr doesn't operate as a copy, hence it isn't compatible with std::vector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You **cannot** use `std::auto_ptr` in `std::vector`. You will need to find an alternative. The problem is that there is no *copy* in `std::auto_ptr`. The copy constructor is in some sense a *move* operation that steals the contents from the original auto pointer and moves it to the new one. That operation requires that the source is a non-const `std::auto_ptr` (as it removes the managed object from it).